# Equivalent to ti = 1:step:len of Matlab in Python

Tags: python, matlab, vector

What is the equivalent of the following MATLAB code that generates a time vector in Python?

```
ti = 1:step:len
```

Comment: [This question](/questions/477486/how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value) is not an exact dupe but it answers your question:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use numpy.arange:

```python
import numpy as np

# ti = np.arange(start, end, step)
ti = np.arange(1,last+step,step)
```

If you want to go from 1 to 10 with 0.5 as the step (including 1 and 10), you would write it as:

```python
ti = np.arange(1,10.5,0.5)
```

If you used `10` as the `end` argument, `ti` would only go to 9.5 because `arange` excludes the `end` value.

Comment: There are other issues with this: `step = 0.7 - 0.4; np.arange(0, 0.9, step)`

Comment: Yes, it is not a perfect method. There is also `np.linspace(start,end,n_steps)`. This will give you both the start and end value and give you a vector with `n_steps` elements.